# Coq: Comparing an Int to a Nat in Separation Logic Foundations

Tags: coq, proof, theorem-proving

Going through [Separation Logic Foundations](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/slf-current/toc.html) and I'm stuck on the exercise triple_mlength in [Repr.v](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/slf-current/Repr.html). I think my current problem is that I don't know how to handle ints and nats in Coq.

```
Lemma triple_mlength: forall (L: list val) (p:loc),
triple (mlength p)
       (MList L p)
       (fun r => \[r = val_int (length L)] \* (MList L p))
```

Check (fun L => val_int (length L)) doesn't throw an error, so that means length is capable of being an int. However, length is opaque and I can't unfold it.

My current context and goal:

```
x : val
p : loc
C : p <> null
x0 : loc
H : p <> null
xs : list val
IH : forall y : list val,
     list_sub y (x :: xs) ->
     forall p, triple (mlength p) 
                      (MList y p) 
                      (fun r:val => \[r = length y] \* MList y p)
______________________________________________________________
length xs + 1 = length (x :: xs)
```

Unsetting print notation the goal transforms into:

```
eq (Z.add (length xs) (Zpos xH)) (length (cons x xs))
```

which I think is trying to add (1:Z) to (length xs: nat), then compare it to (length (cons x xs) : nat)

Types:

```
Inductive nat : Set := O : nat
                     | S : nat -> nat

Inductive Z : Set := Z0 : int 
                   | Zpos : positive -> int 
                   | Zneg : positive -> int

list: forall A, list A -> nat

length: forall A, list A -> nat

val_int: int -> val
```

Coq version is 8.12.2

Answer (score 0):

There is a coercion `nat_to_Z : nat -> int` in scope that is converting `length xs : nat` and `length (x :: xs) : nat` to `int`s. This is separate from the notation mechanism and thus you don't see it when you only ask Coq to show notations. However, it is there and you need to handle it in your proofs. There are a bunch of lemmas floating around that prove equivalence between `nat` operations and `Z`/`int` operations.

Having loaded your file and looked around a bit (`Search` is your friend!), it appears the reason you cannot simplify `length (x :: xs) = S (length xs)` is because there is a lemma `length_cons` which gives `length (x :: xs) = (1 + length xs)%nat`, instead. I suppose the authors of this book thought that would be a good idea for some reason, so they disabled the usual simplification. Do note that "normally" `length` is transparent and `simpl` would work on this goal.

After using `length_cons`, you can use `plus_nat_eq_plus_int` to push the coercion down under the `+`, and then `Z.add_comm` finishes. This line should satisfy the goal.

```
now rewrite length_cons, plus_nat_eq_plus_int, Z.add_comm.
```